# How to easily and cheaply run a simply python script every 5 mins for a whole week - day and night?

Tags: python, server, cloud

I want to run a very simple python script (or any language) which collects data from an api at regular 5 minute intervals and saves the data. I need this process to run for a whole week - day and night. I can't keep my laptop on all week so I guess I will need this to run on some kind of server.

What is the cheapest and easiest way for me to do something like this?
This is an incredibly simple script so I don't want to spend ages setting up a complicated server which is ultimately overkill for a task like this.

Pseudocode:

```
# Every 5 minutes for a whole week:

data = call_api(url)
write_csv(data)
```

Comment: Linux servers often give access to service `cron` ("scheduler") which can run script periodically. But  the cheapest servers may not gives this access or they may block access to external servers - to stop hackers/spamers to access external portals.

Comment: Thanks @furas. What server service do you think would be most appropriate for a task as simple as this?

Comment: I don't know international servers (with English support). I use normal web server in Poland (withou English). I have to add task manually to `cron` - but I have full access to `cron` (without restrictions) and I have full access to external portals - so I can access external APIs. And I have access to server by SSH.

Comment: using Google I found [free web hosting allowing cron jobs](https://www.free-webhosts.com/free-cron.php) but you have to also check if servers give access to external portals. For example [PythonAnywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) gives free access but it block access to external portals - to stop hackers/spamers.

Comment: Thanks @furas! PythonAnywhere is exactly what I have been looking for. Very easy to set up and automate scripts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need a cloud server as it's the cheapest option if u can't setup a system at home. I'll 2nd what furas said about pythonanywhere.com. I use their $5 a month plan to run simple tasks like this. You can cancel anytime so if it's just 1 week then you pay $5 for your account, that's it.

There is no messing around with setup either, just upload your main.py and schedule as task in the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks @James. PythonAnywhere seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Much less of a headache than setting up a server with something like AWS! Super easy to schedule tasks as well. It has already collected a days worth of data :)